# Would it really be this easy to steal peoples bitcoins?

Tags: wallet

I was just looking for an Ethereum wallet app for Android, and something hit me.

Could someone create a wallet app for Android/iOS that simply pretends to create a wallet address but really just displays the address of the one who created the app, causing the victim to transfer his/her funds straight to the app creator instead of their (supposedly) newly created wallet?

This seems too easy...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course this would work.

What do you expect? It's the digital equivalent of walking into a random building with a storefront that vaguely looks like a bank with lots of dollar signs, and then asking "hey i want a bank account, where do I send money?".

Don't install random wallet software. Do research.

Comment: Has this happened (yet)?? Seems like a scam just waiting to happen. I think a lot of people who just got into crypto currencies are uneducated and lazy. If they were looking for a bank they'd just go with the one that their parents or friends have always used, but with apps there are a gazillion and none of them have well known names like "Bank of America" or "Citigroup", so I guess a large portion of people just pick one that sounds (and looks) good and "try it"...

Comment: Yes, there are plenty of cases of scam wallets.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds strange, but something like this happens a lot.

Scammers try everything. They write apps as you described. I have already seen one of them (not in any app store but offered for free on a website). You only need to know Java basics and could program a fake application and some people would fall for it.

They do also write "It's hardfork!! Give us your private key to save your bitcoins during the fork"-websites...